# Stretching images when using as background image

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I was trying to set an image as background image for my django application. But when i set it, it is getting displayed as tiled image. ie without actually stretching the image, same image is tiled and shown 4 times. Can somebody tell me how to stretch the image and set it as a background image. I will paste my code here. I am sure some attribute must be there setting this, which i couldnt find on googling.

```
<body bgcolor=" #408080" background="/static/paper.jpg" background-size: 100%; >
```

Comment: It's not working properly because you're using deprecated markup and trying to use a CSS3 property as an element attribute.

Comment: This is neither Django nor Python related.

Comment: Why don't you resize the image to the right proportions before using it as a background? Wouldn't that help improve the quality also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stretch your background to 100% width and height by putting your image in an `<img>` tag and give it a z-index of -1 so it acts like a background and is behind everything else. This works in all browsers.

```
<img src="..." />

img{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

If you do not want to break the aspect ratio, just set either width or height and not both.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/UXBRM/1/

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a background image on the body tag you should add a image tag right below body, set the position to absolute and a low z-index and then have width=100% and height=100%.

Comment: Won't that distort the picture by breaking the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply this as a style, not as an attribute. That will work if your browser supports CSS 3:

```
style="background: url(/static/paper.jpg); background-size: 100%;"
```

Some background info:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Answer (score 2):

In short: no, you can't stretch the background image with html/css1/css2, you're only options is to either use css3 ( witch is not fully suported by all browsers ) or to use background-attachment and background-repeat css porperties to achieve an alternative result …

Another option would be to use an img tag as a background using z-index css proprety however you'll find it dificult to get it working proprely in all major browsers .

Answer (score 0):

Edit your image with paint. Click *image* and save your image according to your need.

This will work in any html , surely.

Answer (score 0):

As others mention, you should always try to define as much of the attributes in your css and not directly where you have the path to the image itself. This is how it was done way back and is deprecated and probably why it is not working.

use the img src="poefwpf.png" and maybe a  to easy edit in your css:

```
#imgex img {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    (maybe also z-index:-1;)
}
```